# SCCM query for cluster (virtual) name

Tags: sccm, query

I'm trying to determine if the cluster name is stored in SCCM audit data. I see the host name in [v_R_System], and I'm able to identify cluster nodes here. What I need is the virtual name for the cluster nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are talking about windows clustering and not something else then you can [create a MOF file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144376.aspx) to extend hardware inventory to query the cluster name.

You can use powershell to check the cluster name:

```
get-wmiobject -class "MSCluster_Cluster" -namespace "root\mscluster" -computername "virtualName" | select -ExpandProperty name
```

If you have SCCM 2012, an alternative to creating the MOF file is using the ["set classes" in the SCCM console](http://exar.ch/collecting-custom-wmi-classes-with-sccm/).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of powershell, but the goal is to get the data out of the SCCM database via T-SQL query. In Cluster Administrator (Failover Cluster Manager) the cluster name resource is what I'm after. Whether the name is for a SQL Server cluster (which is my primary focus) or just the name of the Windows Cluster, I need to get that name and associate it with the node names. I'll check out the set classes method you've listed.

Comment: @EricHiggins right, then what you'll need to do is to follow the steps to either create the mof file or use the set classes tool.  You need to tell SCCM to collect the cluster name from WMI to populate the SCCM database after which you can create your SCCM queries to view the data.

Comment: I'm sharing this info with my team to determine if we can go the route of custom mof / set classes tool. Would you know what we should enter in the mof file or select in the set classes tool?